# Decoding UTF-8 files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.3, utf8-decode

Alright, so I have tried to wade through the multiple posts about this error,
but unfortunately I am either too tired to understand them, or something is simply eluding me.
Im trying to read a UTF-8 encoded txt file (a backup of my Whatsapp chat history)  and dump it into a variable (for now just printing it), so that I can later do some splitting on its content. 
However, when I run this:

```
protocol = open('C:/chat.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') #use the uft codec, and replace chars u dnt recognize instead of raising errors
print(protocol.read())
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx\src\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(protocol.read())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character   maps to <undefined>
```

I have read some answers using the codec.open() function, but I am simply not entirely sure how to use it. So, I'm sorry if this is the 100th question about this, but I just cant wrap my mind around what exactly the problem is, and how to solve it.

Thanks for your patience and any answers you can provide :)

Comment: The issue here is you are printing back UTF-8 encoded text to your terminal, that presumably doesn't support it. Reading the data is working fine. You don't need to use `codecs.open()` as - given that you are passing `encoding` to `open()`, you must be using Python 3.x, where `open()` has all the functionality of `codecs.open()`.

Comment: So basically, that error has nothing to do with the code, but much rather with my IDE, because it cannot display all the characters in txt file?
*edit*: I tried writing the files instead of displaying them - works as you have already stated. Thanks for explaining! :)